# My onEdit Timestamp script is not working on certain rows despite script conditions being met

Tags: google-apps-script

I made a sheet that uses the script below. On certain rows, it works but on some rows, it doesnt work.

When I investigated, it doesnt work on all the rows marked yes (via formula) on another column, but that column is not even part of the criteria for the script to run the action.

This script was working before and is even working on other sheets but then, is suddenly not working now. any tips? Im not a programmer, i only get these ideas off of this site or youtube or other walkthrough videos available online.

````
var DATETIMELOCATION = [0,1]
var SHEETNAME = '[3] Worksheet'

function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  if( sheet.getSheetName() == SHEETNAME ) { 
    var selectedCell = ss.getActiveCell();
    if( selectedCell.getColumn() == COLUMNTOCHECK) { 
      var dateTimeCell = selectedCell.offset(DATETIMELOCATION[0],DATETIMELOCATION[1]);
      if (dateTimeCell.isBlank()) {dateTimeCell.setValue(new Date()); }
      }
  }
}```
````

Comment: Can you share your sheet?

Answer (score 0):

You say that `it doesn't work on all the rows marked yes (via formula)` and that's normal behavior because the onEdit trigger is only fired for user edits.

[simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)